# How do you say "maybe next time when we visit Japan" in Japanese?

Tags: translation, english-to-japanese

Someone jokingly asked for a present when I wished him happy birthday, and unfortunately he's in Japan and I'm in another country. How can I say:

> Sorry, maybe next time when we visit Japan again.

Maybe in a casual manner? Is:

> "sumimasen, mata kondo de"

appropriate enough?

Answer (score 1):

> 「すみません、また今度で 」
> sumimasen, mata kondo de

is certainly appropriate enough. But, you need to add 「日本{にほん}」 「また今度{こんど}(日本{にほん})であった時で」

Another variation,

> 「ごめん、また次{つぎ}日本{にほん}であった時{とき}に（プレゼントを贈{おく}るよ : I will give you a present.)」

How about that.